# Twitter Rate Limits for Site hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, heroku, memcached

I have a rails application hosted on Heroku using a custom Domain. The application displays the latest Tweet by a single user at the top of each page. To avoid hitting Twitter rate limits (150 requests p/h) I have the application cache the search result in memcache (Dalli) with a 5 minute expiration. This works nicely, ensuring the application only ever makes 12 requests per hour. If it was highly trafficked this solution might be problematic, but as it is I think its fine.

Despite the fact I am well below the rate limits, my site periodically goes down and looking at my server logs it is because I have exceeded Twitter's rate limits.

Is this something to do with Heroku? What else could be causing it? Is it something to do with shared IP addresses?

Logs:

```
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (336.2ms)
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 339ms
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.):
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:             <p class="latest-tweet">
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                 <% if !latest_tweet%>
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                     <% latest_tweet = Twitter.user_timeline("sometwitterusername").first.text %>
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                 <% latest_tweet = Rails.cache.read "latest_tweet" %>
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                     <% Rails.cache.write("latest_tweet", latest_tweet, :expires_in => 5.minutes) %>
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                 <% end %>
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                 <%= latest_tweet %>
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___4472938277532005844_37037700'
2012-02-20T22:09:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4101970984987800094_41561940'
```

Comment: using a custom domain or something.heroku.com? maybe the limit is based on *.heroku.com?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your log. There's nothing here for us to go off of, currently. I doubt it's Heroku (though I suppose it's possible), but we need more information to say what it might be. Also, have you checked your Twitter dev settings to make sure it's not in some kind of demo mode? Are you also absolutely sure that your only hitting Twitter 12 times an hour (maybe each 5 minutes actually has multiple requests, and you don't realize it)?

Comment: @normalocity Sure. Added part of the log. I'm writing my rate limit out to the screen before the Tweet (Getting your rate limit status isn't counted towards your API requests) and I can see it's not decreasing faster than expected.

Comment: @typeoneerror Using a custom domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple. If you share an IP with multiple other developers, you'll share the rate limits as well.

I recommend using authentication to raise this to 350 requests per hour, removing the IP-based limits. This'll simply give *you* 350 requests, regardless of the developers you share the IP with.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case then even upping the limit is not foolproof. All it would take would be 3 other apps approaching the limit on the same IP. This seems crazy to me. So any site hosted on Heroku that hits the Twitter API runs this risk?

Comment: I'm not sure you are sharing the IP with all of Heroku, just the other dynos on that box

Comment: Fwiw, if you authenticate you simply get rid of the IP based limits.

Comment: The IP based limits don't apply when you're authenticating to the API. If you send an OAuth token with the request it doesn't matter if other applications are making requests from your source IPs as it only counts those made with your credentials against your limit (assuming the other applications aren't making some inappropriate number of requests causing the IP to be blacklisted.)

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Yes that all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the Apigee add-on?

https://addons.heroku.com/apigee

This gives you increased rate limits, plus some other bells and whistles.

Comment: Thanks. No I hadn't seen that. Looks like Oauth combined with Apigee should do the trick.

Comment: @Neil "No matches found for ‘apigee’" This is the message showing on heroku for apegee addon

Comment: Apigee is no longer available as an addon