# (twitter) Authentication failure! timeout: Net::OpenTimeout, execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, twitter

So I have a ruby on rails app hosted on `heroku` thats uses the `Twitter API` to send out tweets. Lately the tweets havent been going out, Looking at my logs I see:

```
(twitter) Authentication failure! timeout: Net::OpenTimeout, execution expired
```

**What is causing this? How can I fix it?**

When I bring my `dynos` down to `0` and then back up to `1`, essentially restarting the app the error goes away. But I cant be doing this multiple times a day.

Comment: It is likely a Twitter request rate limiter, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369636/twitter-rate-limits-for-site-hosted-on-heroku?rq=1

Comment: @jan it's not the rate limiter, if it was I would be getting the rate limit error. All tweets sent out on the app are used with different users oauth tokens to avoid hitting a rate limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter was blacklisting some AWS IPs which Heroku are using.

Heroku have been talking to Twitter about a way to resolve this and I understand this is now solved.